# Run function, disable scroll, but enable on callback

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make a infinite scroll page, but I have a problem.

My `loadElements` works with `$.get`, like this:

```
loadElements: function() {
    // fades out page
    $.get(//..).done(function() {// fades in page});
}
```

And scrolling:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    Functions.loadElements();
});
```

What I want is to run `Functions.loadElements();` once on scroll, wait for the `// fades in page`, then reenable scrolling again. I tried `bind/unbind`, but with no success. How can I achieve this?

EDIT:

I tried using `bind` and `unbind` like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    Functions.loadElements();
    $(window).unbind('scroll');
}
```

and in `loadElements`:

```
loadElements: function() {
    // fades out page
    $.get(//..).done(function() {// fades in page; $(window).bind('scroll'); });
}
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: bind/unbind should be what you are looking for according to your question, why didn't this work and what did you try? an alternative would be preventing default event.

Comment: I put a code example in my question that uses `bind`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't give you a solution exactly. but try something like this. You can maintain a status with a globle variable.

```
var isLoading = false; 

    $(window).scroll(function(e) {
        if( !isLoading )
        {
          Functions.loadElements();
          isLoading = true;
        }
       e.preventDefault();
    }

    loadElements: function() {
        // fades out page
        $.get(//..).done(function() {// fades in page; isLoading = false; });
    }
```

Comment: It doesn't change to `false` after load.

Comment: Sometime scope of isLoading variable may not right. so try removing var prefix before isLoading variable.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe instead of rebinding the scroll function that contains the logic, try binding a function that "disables" scrolling and then remove this function once your content is ready to scroll again. You could use [jquery namespace events](http://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/) for this

Try with

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    Functions.loadElements();
    $(window).bind('scroll.StopScroll', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    });
}
```

And then in the `.done` unbind it

```
$(window).unbind('scroll.StopScroll');
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it with the `get` promise

```
var waiting;
$(window).scroll(function(e) {
    if(waiting){
        e.preventDefault();
        return;
    }
    Functions.loadElements().then(function(){
        waiting = false;
    });

    waiting = true;
});
```

and return the `get` promise from `loadElements`

```
loadElements: function() {
    // fades out page
    return $.get(...).done(function() {...});
}
```